# The gcd of coprime polynomials evaluated at integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let $p(x),q(x)$ be coprime squarefree polynomials with
integer coefficients.

For integer $n$ is $\gcd(p(n),q(n))$ bounded by
an absolute constant?

In case the answer is negative what is
the fastest growing function $f(n,\deg(p(x)),\deg(q(x)))$ such that
$\gcd(p(n),q(n)) \ge f(n,\deg(p(x)),\deg(q(x)))$ infinitely
often?

According to another question,
$q(n) \mid p(n)$ can't happen
infinitely often unless $q(x)$
is constant.

For linear polynomials the gcd is bounded.

Comment: Sure: just use Bezout's identity. You have $A(x)p(x) + B(x)q(x) = C$ with $A,B \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $C \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, and then the GCD of any value has to divide $C$.

Comment: The minimal choice of $C$ is called the resultant of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.

Comment: @JeremyRouse No. See: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17501/the-resultant-and-the-ideal-generated-by-two-polynomials-in-mathbbzx

Comment: Oops. Certainly the number $C$ can be taken to be the resultant, but the resultant need not be minimal.