# Ideal generated by two univariate, coprime, integer polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ac.commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $f(x)$, $g(x)$ be two univariate, coprime, integer polynomials and let $I=\big(f(x),g(x)\big)$ the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generated by $f, g$. Let $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$, that is, the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ which can be expressed as linear combinations of $f(x), g(x)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is clearly an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$. The following argument shows that, **given two coprime integer polynomials $f,g$, the ideal $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ has always non zero elements**:

If $f,g$ are considered as elements of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, Bezout's identity tells us that there exists a pair of unique rational polynomials $U(x)$, $V(x)$ with $\deg U<\deg g$, $\deg V<\deg f$ such that
$$
U(x)f(x)+V(x)g(x)=1
$$
Thus, clearing denominators in the above identity, we get that there exists a pair of unique integer polynomials $u(x)$, $v(x)$ with $\deg u<\deg g$, $\deg v<\deg f$ such that
$$
u(x)f(x)+v(x)g(x)=c
$$
where $c$ is the $lcm$ of the denominators of $U,V$ and: $u=cU$, $v=cV$. Thus: $0 \neq c\in I \cap \mathbb{Z}$.

**Question $1$:** Can we determine a sufficient and necessary condition such that: $\mathbb{Z}\subset I \cap \mathbb{Z}$?

**Question $2$:** Is there a general method for determining the least positive generator of $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ ?

*References:*

- [Reduced resultants and Bezout's identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248488/reduced-resultants-and-bezouts-identity)
- [The resultant and the ideal generated by two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17501/the-resultant-and-the-ideal-generated-by-two-polynomials-in-mathbbzx?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Reduced resultant of monic polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227227/reduced-resultant-of-monic-polynomials?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**P.S.:** The second question above, is actually part of the question posted in the first of the references above. However, it is posted here rather as a problem of commutative algebra than a problem of number theory.

Comment: Crossposted from math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1907770/264

Comment: The answer to question 2 is yes, there is a general method.  First, find $c$ as in your post.  After passing to the quotient ring, where we mod out by the ideal $(c)$, you are working in a *finite* ring $(\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z})[x]/(\overline{f}(x),\overline{g}(x))$.  It is then a finite computation to figure out the additive order of $1$ in that ring.

Comment: @Pace Nielsen: thank you for the idea. So, I guess in the example cited in the first reference, $f(x)=2x+1$, $g(x)=2x+17$, it would have been: $\mathbb{Z}_{16}[x]/\big(2x+1\big)$, right?

Comment: @KonKan Yes, and then in that ring we get $1=-2x$, and so $1=(1)^4=(-2x)^4=16x^4=0$ modulo 16.  Thus $1$ belongs to your ideal.

Comment: yes I see. But, you mean $1=0$ modulo $16(2x+1)$ right? Thus, the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{16}[x]/\big(2x+1\big)$ is zero, so $(2x+1)=\mathbb{Z}_{16}[x]$. But in the general case, I mean for higher degree polynomials, we should resort to the use of Gröbner basis techniques, shouldn't we?

Comment: @KonKan Yes, Gröbner basis techniques will work quite effectively.

Comment: @Pace Nielsen: sorry for the misuse of notation in my previous comment. What I had in mind, was that $1=0$ inside $\mathbb{Z}_{16}[x]/(2x+1)\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/(16,2x+1,2x+17)=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x+1,2x+17)$ ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For question 2, compute a Gröbner basis over $\mathbb{Z}$ for the ideal generated by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, which gives the required generator.  You can do this easily in SageMathCloud (available free to use). The algorithm behind this computation is exactly what you would be doing by hand to find the generator. This also answers question 1, if you allow an algorithm to provide a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: thank you very much for the idea. I had this somewhere in the back of my mind but I was hoping to .. avoid it ;) I am not very familiar with Gröbner bases and as far as I remember, the initiall algorithm of Buchberger deals with polynomials over a field. Where can I find smt on how it works in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? P.S.: thanks for mentioning SageMathCloud. I did not knew it.

Comment: Chapter 4 of *An Introduction to Gröbner Bases* by Adams and Loustaunau contains complete details for polynomials with coefficients in a ring where you can compute GCDs. This is implemented in Sage if you apply the groebner_basis method to an ideal generated by polynomials with integer coefficients.  A slight caution: the default in Sage is to use the algorithm from Singular, but apparently this has a bug in the integer implementation, so just use Macauley2, as in I.groebner_basis(algorithm = 'macaulay2:gb'), where I is the ideal. Of course this works for polynomials in several variables too.

Comment: SageMathCloud is a new way to access Sage from any web browser, with no hassles about installing anything. It's amazing, however there's a fairly steep learning curve to use it effectively, but worth the effort if you're going to be using mathematical software.

Comment: thank you very much for your prompt response and the valuable info. One, naive question: How can we be sure that the minimal value of $c$ (that is: the required generator) will always be included in the Grobner basis ?

Comment: It is a property of Gröbner bases that the contraction of an ideal $I$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by those elements in the Gröbner basis which are in $\mathbb{Z}$, and this is one of the main features. This becomes clearer in several variables. If you have an ideal $J\subset\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ and you want to compute the contraction ideal $K = J\cap\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, all you do is compute a Gröbner basis for $J$ using the lex ordering $x<y<z$, and then $K$ is generated by the elements in the Gröbner basis that are polynomials in just $x$ and $y$. See the book by Cox, Little, and O'Shea.

Comment: ok! I think you've made it clear enough. Now I have stuff to study :) thank you for this! One last thing: about the book of Cox, Little, and O'Shea, ( Ideals, varieties and algorithms); does it discuss Grobner bases for ideals inside $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: No, they only consider coefficients in a field, since their main focus is algebraic geometry. In fact, they generally consider algebraically close fields, although the Gröbner basis algorithms don't use this. It's relatively straightforward to adapt these ideas to $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, you just have to replace the division algorithm with cancelling leading terms up to the GCD of the leading coefficients. Roughly speaking, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $k[x]$ are UFDs of dimension 1 (both are PIDs), and so $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $k[x,y]=k[x][y]$ work roughly the same. [CLO] is an *amazing* book!

Comment: I see! your last remark, on the similarity between $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $k[x][y]$ was really helpful. Once again: thank you for for sharing your insight professor Lind.

Comment: You're very welcome. Again, the book by Cox, Little, and O'Shea will give you excellent insight into the connections between these algebraic ideas and geometric ones. At the large annual meeting of the American Mathematical Society held last January in Seattle their book was awarded a big prize, and very well deserved.