# For two polynomials, what is the relationship between the least linear combination and the resultants?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

Let $k$ be a field and $k[x]$ be the ring of polynomials over $k$. Given two polynomis $m_1(x), m_2(x) \in k[x]$,  I want to know the relationship between the resultants and the least linear combination.

(In Euclidean rings, the least linear combination is the greatest common divisor (GCD).)

Comment: What kind of relationship could there possibly be? The resultant is a scalar, not a polynomial.

Comment: If we simplify the sylvester matrix of m1(x) and m2(x) to a row echelon form, we can transform the non-zero row at the bottom of the matrix into polynomial form which is exactly the least linear combination.

Comment: If the resultant is $0$, then the GCD has positive degree; if the resultant is nonzero, then the GCD is $1$. I recall some more interesting questions about this where $k$ is a ring, but there isn't anything more to say about a field.

Comment: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ be a composite number. So $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ is not an integral domain. Through the experimental results, the above reply is still valid in $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ .

Comment: Could you please tell me some more interesting questions about this where $k$ is a ring?

Comment: Related questions, over rings: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227227/reduced-resultant-of-monic-polynomials and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17501/the-resultant-and-the-ideal-generated-by-two-polynomials-in-mathbbzx and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248488/reduced-resultants-and-bezouts-identity and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248574/ideal-generated-by-two-univariate-coprime-integer-polynomials and probably others. Search reduced resultant site:mathoverflow.net and related questions in the results you get.

Comment: I was remembering the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17501 and its many interesting answers.

Comment: Have you had a look, worm, at those links I gave?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved my problem well according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The important notion here is that of [subresultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Subresultants). Suppose $P_1, P_2$ are two polynomials of degrees $d_1,d_2$ and suppose $d_1\ge d_2$. To compute the GCD you would typically use Euclid's division algorithm: you divide $P_1$ by $P_2$ and get a remainder $P_3$ then you divide $P_2$ by $P_3$ and get the remainder $P_4$ etc. The last nonzero remainder is the GCD. Now imagine doing that for **generic** polynomials
$$
P_1(x)=a_{1,d_1}x^{d_1}+a_{1,d_1-1}x^{d_1-1}+\cdots+a_{1,1}x+a_{1,0}
$$
and
$$
P_2(x)=a_{2,d_2}x^{d_2}+a_{2,d_2-1}x^{d_2-1}+\cdots+a_{2,1}x+a_{2,0}\ .
$$
The very first step would be to subtract $\frac{a_{1,d_1}}{a_{2,d_2}}x^{d_1-d_2}P_2(x)$ from $P_1(x)$. Don't do that. Instead multiply $P_1$ by $a_{2,d_2}$ and then subtract $a_{1,d_1}x^{d_1-d_2}P_2(x)$ so as not to produce fractions. Rince and repeat.
Generically the degree of the remainder only drops by one. The resultant essentially is the degree zero remainder, i.e., $P_{d_2+2}$. The previous $P$'s are the subresultants (up to one's choice of normalization convention, there may also be extraneous factors to peel off).

A good reference on the subject is the book "Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry" by Basu, Pollack and Roy.